# Array of objects not altered after first file write

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I have an empty array in a remote file but intend to momentarily add and alter objects in it. However, after adding an initial first set of objects, the array does not accept any more values. My error log reports `unexpected 'Object' (T_STRING), expecting ')'` meaning it regards the keyword "Object" as a string imputed by me so I guess the problem originates from my array structure. Here is the code I used in adding the objects

```
include 'all_users.php';

$francis_udeh = new Admin("francis_udeh");
$all_users['francis_udeh'] = $francis_udeh;

$victor_nwafor = new Member("victor_nwafor");
$all_users['victor_nwafor'] = $victor_nwafor;
$print_arr = print_r($all_users, TRUE);

$updated_arr = "<?php \n \$all_users = $print_arr; \n?>";
file_put_contents('all_users.php', $updated_arr);
```

returns the following in the remote file

```
<?php 
$all_users = Array
(
[francis_udeh] => Admin Object
    (
        [name] => francis udeh
        [pagename] => francis.udeh
        [can_comment] => 1
        [can_view_announcements] => 1
        [profile_pic] => /blog/accounts/assets/user.png
        [can_delete_comment] => 1
    )

[victor_nwafor] => Member Object
    (
        [name] => victor nwafor
        [pagename] => victor.nwafor
        [can_comment] => 1
        [can_view_announcements] => 1
        [profile_pic] => /blog/accounts/assets/user.png
    )

 );

 ?>
```

(which, by the way, is what I want). However, when I try

```
include 'all_users.php';
$raheem_sadiq = new Member("raheem_sadiq");
$all_users['raheem_sadiq'] = $raheem_sadiq;
$print_arr = print_r($all_users, TRUE);

$updated_arr = "<?php \n \$all_users = $print_arr; \n?>";
file_put_contents('all_users.php', $updated_arr);
```

it returns the error I posted earlier resulting in the array not changing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You include all_users.php at the beginning of code, but after first file_put_contents() it's a not correct php code in this file.

Answer (score 2):

As @Indra already mentioned: the output given by print_r() is human readable, but not valid php code. If you don't have the possibilty to pass the data via a data storage (like mysql), it might be a workaround to put it to the file with serialize(). Alternatively, you could also use json (as your objects seem to be data access objects of some same kind) and then instantiate the objects remotely. 
Hope this helps, 
Greetings

Comment: I'm still stuck. The decode function does not work
`$json_arr = json_encode($all_users);

$updated_arr = "<?php \n \$all_users='$json_arr'\n?>";
file_put_contents('all_users.php', $updated_arr); 
$output = json_decode('$all_users');
var_dump($output);
echo json_last_error();`

Comment: @Mmayboy What is the problem with the new code? It's hard for people to help you unless you provide the output, including any error messages.

Comment: You should also probably know it's very unusual to dynamically create a PHP file with the data written in to it. Why don't you just write the JSON to a file and then read it back when you need it?

Comment: the best way in this case (even if data handling this way might seem a bit strange) would be to serialize the array like `$serialized_array = serialize($all_users); file_put_contents('data_file_name', $serialized_array);` and read it from file like `$all_users = unserialize(file_get_contents('data_file_name'));` Hope this helps.

Comment: @ndo that didnt work either. The error message says `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Member could not be converted to string`. Chris I need to write it dynamically this first time because I'll be dynamically writing it in in future. What I'm doing now is actually test running against the future times to see if it works but apparently no one in God;s green earth can help me.

Comment: @Chris I need an object oriented system where I can differentiate between page viewer and page owner, add friends, upvote comments etc etc so the database thingy won't/can't cut it for me here. I need a persistent array of users rather than ragamuffins downvoting my question. I hope you understand?

Comment: @Mmayboy, that's not really a reason for creating a PHP file dynamically. A standard data file would work fine for that.

Comment: Also, I've just ran @ndo's code and it seems to be working fine for me. Which line is the fatal error thrown on?

Comment: @Chris I have to initialize the file as an array so whenever I unserialize or decode, I have an array which I can loop through and alter user preferences and serialize back!

Comment: Right, but you should serialize and deserialize in to a data file, not a PHP file!

Comment: @Chris what format is the data file in and how do I convert it to a PHP array after unserializing?

Comment: @Mmayboy The data file is in the format of a PHP serialized value and the act of deserializing it is what converts it in to a PHP array (assuming an array was what was serialized in the first place).

Comment: @Mmayboy No, that's not what you are doing. Your first problem is that you are still trying to treat `all_users.php` as a PHP file. It stops being a PHP file the moment you write serialized data to it. The reason you are getting the error though is that your syntax for echoing the value of an object property is completely wrong. `print_r($all_users)` and you'll find it's been deserialized exactly as you want.

Comment: @Chris that worked, albeit partially but thanks. I did `$all_users = unserialize(file_get_contents('all_users.php'));print_r($all_users['francis_udeh']->name);` and [http://blog.agwconitsha.org/login/add_object.php] (it blurted out the entire serialized array then the name I requested for) in the end. I then tried `$all_users = unserialize(file_get_contents('all_users.php'));
$workable_arr = print_r($all_users, TRUE);
echo "$workable_arr['francis_udeh']->name";` and the result was almost the same, though worse. But thanks for sticking around with me till now! :)

Comment: @Mmayboy the reason it blurts out the entire serialized array is because you are doing `include "all_users.php`. `all_users.php` is not a PHP file, it's where you wrote your serialized data. Don't include it in your `add_object.php` script.

Comment: @Chris Oh! My bad. It should now be treated as a bland file. One last thing: Due to its delicate nature, I'll need to prevent public access to that all_users file but even after reducing its permissions to `read and write for only "user"` I can still open it from my browser. Is there a workaround this besides .htaccess locking hotlinking of files?

Comment: @Mmayboy, you should be able to use htaccess to block access to that file completely. Alternatively, you can store it outside of your web root.